# What makes a seemingly legit question off topic?

Tags: support

To my surprise [Why can't I remap q](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22227/why-cant-i-remap-q) has been closed as OT.

What makes it off topic? (I don't want to argue or discuss but merely get some insight)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** Changed a bit the phrasing of my answer because I confused @guntbert (OP of this meta question) thinking they were @Joe Compton (OP of the referenced question)

I marked it as off topic because of the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error.**

I marked it because Joe Compton already had written an answer so their reputation is not impacted but future readers are unlikely to benefit from the question as it is unlikely that they make the same typographical mistake.

However it doesn't indicate a poor quality of the question, just an unlikely re usability.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - I saw it as having the docs misunderstood. In any case I have no part in the Q - just a curious bystander :-)

Comment: Oh I went a bit too fast and confused you with the question's OP :) Note that questions based on a misunderstanding of the doc can still be on topic or at least can still get an answer. It really depends on the question.